# multiple analog inputs to produce individual averages for each channel

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, arduino, average, smoothing

I am trying to put four analog inputs into individual channels that contain an array. Once that happens I am trying to get an average of each channel's array getting a single int or float. Lastly, I want to compare the averages in an if statement to get a serial print and divide the compared averages.

I am just confused on what in the code I pieced together is necessary.

Thank you for any advice or help.

Here is my code below

```
#include <Servo.h> 
float sVal0 = 0.0;
float sVal1 = 0.0;
float sVal2 = 0.0;
float sVal3 = 0.0;
float sVal02 = 0.0;
float sVal13 = 0.0;

const int numReadings = 10;         //# of readings needed to average
const int numChannels = 4;          // 4 analog outputs

int readings[numChannels][numReadings];      // the readings from the analog input
int index;              // the index of the current reading


void setup () {
Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop () {
 sVal0 = analogRead(A0);
 sVal1 = analogRead(A1);
 sVal2 = analogRead(A2);
 sVal3 = analogRead(A3);


for (int chan = 0; chan <= numChannels; ++chan ){
  Serial.println(sVal0[chan]);   // serial print each array 
  Serial.println(sVal1[chan]);
  Serial.println(sVal2[chan]);
  Serial.println(sVal3[chan]);

for (int thisReading = 0; thisReading < numReadings; thisReading++) {
  readings[thisReading] = 0;
  index = index + 1;
}

if (index >= numReadings) {
index = 0;
sVal0_avg = sVal0[chan]/numReadings;   // get average
sVal1_avg = sVal0[chan]/numReadings;
sVal2_avg = sVal0[chan]/numReadings;
sVal3_avg = sVal0[chan]/numReadings;
}
}

if (sVal1_avg > sVal3_avg) {
Serial.print("1 avg: );
Serial.println(sVal1_avg);

sVal31 = sVal3_avg / sVal1_avg;
Serial.print("comparison : ");
Serial.println(sVal31);
}
}
```

Comment: That code won't compile (or shouldn't).  sVal0 is not an array, it is a float.  You can't put brackets behind it and expect it to suddenly be an array of something.

Comment: Arrays if you want to use them as arrays.  Do you want to take ten readings in a row from one pin and then ten from the next or do you want to take ten readings on each pin one at a time?  Do you want a rolling average or just an average every ten samples?

Comment: An average over time needs time, which I do not see in your sketch.

Comment: Do you need to interleave all the channel measurements? If not, make it simpler by doing one channel at a time: accumulate the measurements on the fly, then get its average, then go to the next channel. Less storage, less logic. Even if you have to get the four channels together, you don't need to store each individual sample - just accumulate the values and calculate the average at the end.